# How to use pass filename without extension to gedit external tool for make?

Tags: bash, compiling, make, gcc, gedit

I am wanting to build and run a program called dbgen using the external tools. I know that this variable holds the filename, ‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍`dbgen.c‍‍` :

```
$GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_NAME
```

How do I remove the `.c` part so I can use it here for any file name:

```
#!/bin/sh
make dbgen
./dbgen
```

In addition, I would like to know how I can check if a `makefile` exists, if not, use some default flags on `gcc` instead, like `CFLAGS=-Wall -g`

## Tool Window:

[image]

Comment: It is not clear where you are trying to program/achive something. Are you using a shell or are you doing something in a settings window of gedit? Or something else? What are the external tools? How is the file name and .c suffix question related to the second code block?

Comment: @Lucas please see update.

Answer (score 1):

**Remove extension:**

Try to use the `${varname%.ext}` expansion of sh/bash/zsh. For example like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
# ...
file_name_with_out_ext="${GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_NAME%.c}"
```

(but beware that this will only remove .c extionsions and leave .h or .cpp, or any other extensions alone)

**Test if file exists:**

You can test if a file exists (for example a makefile) in the shell (sh/bash/zsh) with the `test` or `[` command or the `[[` builtin:

```
test -e some_file_name && echo exists
[ -e some_file_name ] && echo exists
[[ -e some_file_name ]] && echo exists
```

Be sure to check the man page for test(1), bash(1) or zshbuiltins(1).

**Make file flags:**

Do you mean something like this:

```
if [[ -e makefile ]]; then 
  make CFLAGS='-Wall -g' my_target
else
  make my_target
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the extension use something like this-

```
echo $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_NAME | sed 's/\..*$//'
```